# How to enable this credentials-picker from Google in my site?

Tags: google-chrome, google-signin

I'd like to integrate an auto-login pop-up as the one displayed in https://www.lequipe.fr

It detects your session in the browser and asks you if you want to join with your Google Account.

How can I implement this in my website? ( I already have Google Sign in ) - is using the GAPI API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's [Google One-tap sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web), it can be integrated using their API, follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) to setup Google One Tap in your website.

When you have added the Oauth2 ClientID in Google console. You would just use something like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="XXXXXXXXXXXX-bk2lj5rs6l4c6g23nmtsfdh66qhfu921.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-login_uri="https://localhost:3000/login"
    >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and you would get :

[image]

Comment: What is data-login_uri here?